# Как правильно отобразить один item в RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Необходимо чтобы не весь список сразу отображался, а по очереди с 0 до list.size(), если пользователь свайпнул

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ApiService service;
private RecyclerView itemList;
private LinearLayoutManager horizontalLinearLayoutManager;
private ItemAdapter adapter;
private List<Feed.FeedData> items = new ArrayList<>();
private Feed data;
ImageView iv_avatar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    iv_avatar = findViewById(R.id.iv_avatar);

    service = RetrofitBuilder.createService(ApiService.class);
    itemList = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    itemList.setLayoutManager(manager);
    adapter = new ItemAdapter(items);
    itemList.setAdapter(adapter);
    loadItems();


}

private void loadItems() {
    service.getFeed().enqueue(new Callback<Feed>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Feed> call, Response<Feed> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                data = response.body();
                items.addAll(data.getData());
                adapter.setItems(items);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Feed> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

private class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewHolder> {
    private List<Feed.FeedData> items;

    public ItemAdapter(List<Feed.FeedData> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Feed.FeedData> items) {
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Feed.FeedData item = items.get(position);
        holder.bind(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}

private class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_name;
    TextView tv_location;
    TextView tv_text;
    TextView tv_for_likes;
    ImageView iv_avatar;
    ImageView iv_avatar_location;


    private ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
        tv_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
        tv_for_likes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_for_likes);
        iv_avatar_location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_avatar_location);
        iv_avatar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_avatar);
    }

    void bind(Feed.FeedData type) {
        //if (type.getUser().getUserData().getAvatarUrl() != null && type.getUser().getUserData().getAvatarUrl().isEmpty()) {}
        Picasso.get().load(type.getImage()).into(iv_avatar_location);
        Picasso.get().load(type.getUser().getUserData().getAvatarUrl()).into(iv_avatar);
        tv_location.setText(type.getCity().getCityData().getName());
        tv_name.setText(type.getUser().getUserData().getName());
        tv_text.setText(type.getText());
        tv_for_likes.setText(String.valueOf(type.getUser().getUserData().getLikesCount()));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел достаточно легкий способ решения моего вопроса, с помощью SnapHelper(); 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324926/swipe-one-item-at-a-time-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант. У первого элемента выставить высоту `match_parent`, а при скроллинге сразу поменять на `wrap_content` или фиксированное значение.

Answer (score 0):

Передать в адаптер List  с один итемом, а при свайпе передать весь список и сделать

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```